# Texture painting using Stencil is blurry on some models (Blender 2.82)

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I know I'm probably doing something wrong or not understanding something but when I try to texture paint using Stencil on 3 objects, 1 flat circle, 1 plane, and 1 long rectangle (long cube), the texture is appearing blurry on the rectangle. The details:

- All of them are unwrapped using Smart UV Project
- All of them uses the same Texture and settings upon painting
- All the texture they use (Base Color) are 2048x2048 (I also tried 4096x4096, it seemed to improved but still blurry for the rectangle)

Here are some screenshots:

[image: The circle]

[image: The plane]

[image: The rectangle]

As you can see in the screenshots, the last one (rectanlge) is blurry. The image texture is 3264x2448 if that helps.

Comment: But the first two that are okay, look at how much pixel real estate they are giving to the painted area, and then compare the third that is blurry - look at how little fo the image is being painted for the same are almost in the 3d view. I would try another unwrap on that one to see if it can be given more pixels per face so that the paint to target ratio is smaller.

Comment: Try to give it a little more geometry.